# What is the underlying function for the "shotgun" polar pattern?

Tags: functions

I'm trying to reproduce the polar patterns displayed at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microphone#Polar_patterns. Functions are of type $r(\theta) = \alpha + (1-\alpha)cos(\theta), \alpha \in [0,1]$ (with logarithmic radius for display) but the last one ("shotgun") seems to be different. Does anybody know what is the underlying function ?

[image: Polar patterns]

Answer (score 0):

I started off with $\cos(2\theta)$ to make a 4 petal pattern.

Then, I subtracted $0.5$, a small, arbitrary constant, to reduce the size of the horizontal petals.

Finally, I added $\sin(\theta)$ to increase the size of the top petal.

Indeed it's quite rough, but $\cos(2\theta)-0.5+\sin(\theta)$ makes the approximate shape. Play with the coefficients, I suppose.

The only discord between my function and yours is that it looks horizontally squished.

Comment: I tried something similar but then I'm unable to squish it. The shape seems to be referenced a lot related to microphone and I would have expected a simple function (like for the others).